# how to get the HREF value using POST

Tags: php, html

I'm making a dynamic menu where each link in my dropdown menu will be directed to a page base on the ID in the HREF link. How can I POST the ID from my link?

Here's my code:

```html
<?php
$lesson_sql = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE lessonID = 1";
$lesson_query = mysqli_query($db, $lesson_sql);
$lesson = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lesson_query);
?>
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <div class="navmenu">
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Catalog</strong></a><span class="darrow"></span>
                <ul class="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a>
                        <ul class="sub1_1">
                            <?php
                            do {
                                ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="lesson1.1.php?lessonID=<?php echo $lesson['lessonID'];?>">
                                        <?php echo $lesson['lessonName']; ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <?php
                            }while ($lesson = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lesson_query));
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the code from the code above I wanted to get the ID, its beside the href value.

```
<li><a href="lesson1.1.php?lessonID=<?php echo $lesson['lessonID'];?>"><?php echo $lesson['lessonName']; ?></a></li>
```

Sorry for my english, I hope you understand me!

Comment: I don't believe you can, not directly at least. You can simulate it using AJAX by binding to the click event, or make it into a button in a form. What's wrong with GET in this case though? Or using some URL rewriting if it's the look of the URL that's making you think of using this route?

Comment: Any reason to not just use GET?

Comment: @JonStirling how can I do it sir?

Comment: can I use GET instead? how can I do it?

Comment: you can use GET method and access id as $_GET['lessonID'].

Comment: @Yogendrasinh $lesson($_GET['lessonID']) --- is this correct sir?

Comment: I have written it as answer below. please check it.

Comment: No. What? How'd you get to that? It looks like you need to learn the PHP basics before continuing, then you wouldn't need to ask. Find some tutorials and work through them. It will help in the long run.

Comment: @JonStirling I will sir! I will also search your given answer so I can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `lesson1.1.php` file you can use `$_GET` to access the id as below.

```
$id = $_GET["lessonID"];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have query string then you use

```
 $_GET['name of control']
```